# Does Flash/AS3 process the RTLO and RTLE Unicode characters?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, unicode

Based on [this report](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Backwards-Unicode-names-hides-malware-and-viruses-1242114.html), I'm wondering if Flash/AS3 also processes the right-to-left override and right-to-left embed characters?

For example, would a chat program implemented in AS be vulnerable to someone using RTLO/RTLE to circumvent profanity filters (e.g. writing "\u202E!nmad" to write "damn!") or impersonate another user (e.g. putting "\u202EmoT" as their username to show up as "Tom")?

If this is true, what countermeasures can be taken to avoid these issues?

Comment: filter what they can type in the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with the text renderer rather than ActionScript as such. If you're using the new Flash 10 text renderer that supports bidirectional and complex text layout, then yes, user input may render in an unexpected way. The new text renderer is used by classes such as `TextLine`. You can see this in action by pasting something like:

```
well‮!nmad!
```

into the text layout example demo at http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=442.

In the old text renderer you won't get this, but you also won't be able to render complex scripts properly either.

When you are accepting untrusted user input for inclusion in a wider string of text, whether or not Flash is involved, you should filter out these characters. A good group to choose to filter out is the one described by W3C as [not suitable for use in markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/#Suitable). This includes the bidi overrides and a bunch of other generally troublesome control codes.

I would recommend most web applications routinely filter out all of these, as well as all the ASCII and C1 control codes other than newline (U+0000–U+0009, U+000B–U+001F, U+007F–U+009F).

(Profanity filters aren't a compelling reason to disallow bidi IMO—they're so easily fooled by almost anything that it's not even worth bothering.)

Comment: Very good answer! Thanks for the text layout demo and the W3C link, hadn't found those before. :) And you are right about profanity filters. But impersonating another user (or even moderator) is a serious issue.